# Time series (stochastic process) estimating parameters using characteristic function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, parameter-estimation, time-series

I have a time series of assets ${A_1, A_2, ..., A_n}$, which is described by a sophisticated distribution having the following characteristic function:  $\phi(u; t;\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a vector of unknown parameters. 
I need to esimate vector of unknown parameters $\theta$ of characteristic function.

I tried to find a PDF using the inverse Fourier transform to use the maximum likelihood method, but the characteristic function is too complicated for that.
I also thought about building the empirical characteristic function using the time series of assets and to estimate parameters using the least square method, but I do not know how to build the empirical characteristic function, because time series is not just a sample of random variables, it is a random process that depends on time.

Comment: Also asked here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38681/time-series-stochastic-process-estimating-parameters-using-characteristic-func